# Why my WP emulator stops on splashscreen

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I created a WP Class Library **BusinessLogic** project which is composed by these three class

1) **Bottle** Class

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class Bottle : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Due to INotifyPropertyChanged interface
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Proprietà Title
        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            set
            {
                if (title != value)
                {
                    title = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Title");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return title;
            }
        }
        // Proprietà PhotoFileName
        private string photoFileName;
        public string PhotoFileName
        {
           set
            {
                if (photoFileName != value)
                {
                    photoFileName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PhotoFileName");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return photoFileName;
            }
        } 
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propChanged)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propChanged));
    }
  }
}
```

2) **Bottles** Class

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class Bottles : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Due to INotifyPropertyChanged interface
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Proprietà MainTitle
        private string mainTitle;
    public string MainTitle
    {
        set
        {
            if (mainTitle != value)
            {
                mainTitle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MainTitle");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return mainTitle;
        }
    }

    // Proprietà bottles
    private ObservableCollection<Bottle> bottleSet = new ObservableCollection<Bottle>();
    public ObservableCollection<Bottle> BottleSet
    {
        set
        {
            if (bottleSet != value)
            {
                bottleSet = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BottleSet");
            }
        }
        get { return bottleSet; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propChanged)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propChanged));
    }

}
}
```

3) **BottlesPresenter** Class

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class BottlesPresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    // Due to INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    // Proprietà BottleMatrix
    private Bottles bottlesMatrix;
    public Bottles BottlesMatrix
    {
        protected set
        {
            if (bottlesMatrix != value)
            {
                bottlesMatrix = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BottlesMatrix");
            }
        }
        get { return bottlesMatrix; }
    }

    public BottlesPresenter()
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Bottles));

        using (StreamReader fileReader = new         StreamReader(@"C:\Stuff\WindowsPhone\AppLearningHowTo2\AppLearningHowTo2\DAL\DB.xml"))
        {
            BottlesMatrix = (Bottles)xml.Deserialize(fileReader);
        }
    }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propChanged)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propChanged));
        }
    }
}
```

The BottlePresenter constructor should deserialize from an xml file located into the file system. It contains the following tags

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Bottles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MainTitle>MainTitle</MainTitle>
  <Bottleset>
    <Bottle>
      <Title>Title1</Title>
      <PhotoFileName>PhotoFileName1</PhotoFileName>
    </Bottle>
    <Bottle>
      <Title>Title2</Title>
      <PhotoFileName>PhotoFileName2</PhotoFileName>
    </Bottle>
  </Bottleset>
</Bottles>
```

Then I created a WP Application and I made a reference to the **BusinessLogic.dll** project library.

In the MainPage.xaml file I put the XML namespace declaration

```
xmlns:businesslogic="clr-namespace:BusinessLogic;assembly=BusinessLogic"
```

I then instantiated the **BottlesPresenter** class in the MainPage.xaml Resources collection

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <businesslogic:BottlesPresenter x:Key="bottlesPresenter" />        
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And finally put a TextBlock in the content area with a binding to that resource:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource bottlesPresenter},
                                  Path=Bottles.MainTitle}" />
```

Unfortunately I launch the debugger, the emulator switch on, reach the splashscreen and doesn't go on.

In a nutshell: I can't reach to create an instance of the **BottlesPresenter** class.

I banged my head against the wall for weeks without finding a solution.

Please could someone give me a hand?

Thank you very much

Antonio

Comment: Any debug output? Do you reach any breakpoints? If you remove the references to bottlesPresenter does it at least load the first page? Can you post a full repro?

Comment: Hi Matt. No debug Output and no breakpoints reached. Removing the references the first page loads without any trouble. What do you mean with "post a full repro"? I didn't find a way to upload the entire solution on StackOverFlow. Anyway if you give me your email address I can send you the solution. Many many many Thanks. Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Emulator behaves like that when WP7 cannot construct Application object. From question, I see only 1 reference from Application to your code. It's BottlePresenter in Resources.
XamlLoader tries to create instance of this type.

See what's inside your BottlePresenter constructur:

```
public BottlesPresenter()
{
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Bottles));

    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(
    @"C:\Stuff\WindowsPhone\AppLearningHowTo2\AppLearningHowTo2\DAL\DB.xml"))
    {
        BottlesMatrix = (Bottles)xml.Deserialize(fileReader);
    }
}
```

First line is OK.
Second line is OK.
Third line causes exception, because path "C:\Stuff\WindowsPhone\AppLearningHowTo2\AppLearningHowTo2\DAL\DB.xml" is not acceptable on Windows Phone.
All files you can access is Content of your XAP, Resources in your assembly, and files in Isolated Storage.

Following articles might help you [All about WP7 Isolated Storage - Read and Save Text files](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files)